# Rails 5.1 Route Constraint Not Passing Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im having an issue after updating to Rails 5.1 with a route constraint.

Basically my route is matching, but no params are being passed through to the controller action.  This code has been working for a while, but now it doesn't and im kind of stuck as to why.

Hitting the URL

```
localhost:3000/?edd_action=activate_license&item_name=ProductA&license=123
```

Route

```
get '/' => 'api/v1/legacy_licenses#activate', constraints: { query_string: /edd_action=activate_license/ }
```

My action code looks like

```
def load_license_key
    if params[:license]
     ...
    end
  end
```

The problem is the params hash never picks up the license param, or the item name one for that matter.

If I inspect the `request.query_string` on that action all I see is `"edd_action=activate_license"`  so I don't know where the rest of the params are going.

Can anyone help?  Changing the URL params isn't an option as its only like this to integrate with legacy software.

Comment: /edd_action=activate_license/ just match "edd_action=activate_license". Have you tried something like `/edd_action=activate_license.+/` to match all params after `edd_action`?

Comment: Yea I tried /edd_action=activate_license.*/ but its still the same